# Interface names based on mac address

Tags: 16.04, networking, server, systemd

I am trying to configure systemd to use the [4th naming rule](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/) which bases the name on the mac address. I have created a .link file like this:

```
[Match]

[Link]
NamePolicy=mac
```

However, after a restart it still names my interface: *enp1s0* - not *enx*. I have named the file 1file.link and inserted it into */etc/systemd/network/*.

I don't know if something is missing, if it works but priority 3 rule kicks in before or if the problem is something else.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that I was missing 1 step. After changing the interface name I still needed to update the */etc/network/interface* file according to the new interface name. The new name can be found by calling *ifconfig -a*. And finally a restart.

I stil don't know if this step can be automated somehow?